# reduce output using SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

data in tables is:

Ticket table

```
Ticket_Nbr            ,  aaa.pnr_ticket_id
2303167095666         ,  5889503
2         ,  2345
3         ,  3456
4         ,  4567
5         ,  5678
```

Coupon table

```
CPN_FRM_SER       ,  CPN_NUM,  FRM_CITY,  TO_CITY
2303167095666     ,  1      ,  SCL     ,  PTY
2303167095666     ,  2      ,  PTY     ,  SFO
2303167095666     ,  3      ,  SFO     ,  SEA
2303167095666     ,  4      ,  SEA     ,  SFO
```

Query is:

```
    SELECT 
    XMLElement
    (
        "Eticket", 
        XMLElement("Ticket", XMLAttributes(t.ticket_nbr AS "NBR")), 
        (
            SELECT XMLAGG(XMLElement("COUPON", XMLAttributes(c.cpn_num AS "COUPON_NUM", c.frm_city AS "FROM_CITY", c.to_city AS "TO_CITY")))
            FROM coupon c
            WHERE c.cpn_frm_ser = t.ticket_nbr
        ) AS "coupon"
    )
FROM ticket t,
    coupon c
WHERE c.cpn_frm_ser = t.ticket_nbr
    AND t.aaa_pnr_ticket_id = '5889503';
```

Output generated is:

```
<Eticket>
  <Ticket NBR="2302167019566"></Ticket>
  <AAA_PNR_TICKET ISSUE_DATE="2017-02-13" HA_CC="CM"></AAA_PNR_TICKET>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="1" FROM_CITY="SCL" TO_CITY="PTY"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="2" FROM_CITY="PTY" TO_CITY="SFO"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="3" FROM_CITY="SFO" TO_CITY="SEA"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="4" FROM_CITY="SEA" TO_CITY="SFO"></COUPON>
</Eticket>
<Eticket>
  <Ticket NBR="2302167019566"></Ticket>
  <AAA_PNR_TICKET ISSUE_DATE="2017-02-13" HA_CC="CM"></AAA_PNR_TICKET>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="1" FROM_CITY="SCL" TO_CITY="PTY"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="2" FROM_CITY="PTY" TO_CITY="SFO"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="3" FROM_CITY="SFO" TO_CITY="SEA"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="4" FROM_CITY="SEA" TO_CITY="SFO"></COUPON>
</Eticket>
<Eticket>
  <Ticket NBR="2302167019566"></Ticket>
  <AAA_PNR_TICKET ISSUE_DATE="2017-02-13" HA_CC="CM"></AAA_PNR_TICKET>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="1" FROM_CITY="SCL" TO_CITY="PTY"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="2" FROM_CITY="PTY" TO_CITY="SFO"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="3" FROM_CITY="SFO" TO_CITY="SEA"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="4" FROM_CITY="SEA" TO_CITY="SFO"></COUPON>
</Eticket>
<Eticket>
  <Ticket NBR="2302167019566"></Ticket>
  <AAA_PNR_TICKET ISSUE_DATE="2017-02-13" HA_CC="CM"></AAA_PNR_TICKET>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="1" FROM_CITY="SCL" TO_CITY="PTY"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="2" FROM_CITY="PTY" TO_CITY="SFO"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="3" FROM_CITY="SFO" TO_CITY="SEA"></COUPON>
  <COUPON COUPON_NUM="4" FROM_CITY="SEA" TO_CITY="SFO"></COUPON>
</Eticket>
```

The same line of output data repeated 4 times.

I am looking for only one output line of data, instead of 4 lines, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: if the data are the same but you need  unique use distinct

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: You join in the `coupon` in your main query and then NEVER use it. Take that thing out. Just `FROM ticket t;` and your problem will go away.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join the coupon table outside. Just the correlated subquery is enough.

```
select XMLElement("Eticket",
            XMLElement("Ticket", XMLAttributes(t.ticket_nbr as "NBR")),
            (
            select XMLAGG(
                XMLElement(
                    "COUPON", 
                    XMLAttributes(
                        c.cpn_num as "COUPON_NUM",
                        c.frm_city as "FROM_CITY",
                        c.to_city as "TO_CITY"
                        )
                    )
                )
            from coupon c
            where c.cpn_frm_ser = t.ticket_nbr
            ) as "coupon")
from ticket t
where t.aaa_pnr_ticket_id = '5889503';
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/IHC73556)

Comment: I believe your group by is superfluous assuming that `ticket_nbr` is the key on the `ticket` table.